Link post images to media file automatically
I have blog posts that have several images (each with 50-70 images). Manually adding links to each image to their media file is very cumbersome.
What I'm looking for is a way to add a link to the original media file around the image in the "core/image" block, allowing users to click on the image and navigate to the full-size version of the image.
I have this script:
    function link_wp_block_image_to_media( $block_content, $block ) {
    if ( 'core/image' === $block['blockName'] ) {
        if ( strpos( $block_content, '<a ' ) === false ) {
            preg_match( '/src="(.*?)"/', $block_content, $matches );
            $image_url = $matches[1];
            $block_content = preg_replace( '/<img(.*?)>/', '<a href="' . $image_url . '" class="fade--in">$0</a>', $block_content );
        }
    }
    return $block_content;
}
add_filter( 'render_block', 'link_wp_block_image_to_media', 10, 2 ); 

but it has its own issues such as:

It adds links to all the image on a page whereas I need this functionality for a specific container called ".story"
It also doesn't add link to images where there's a text link within <figcaption>

What I'm looking for a simple way to make all images within a container link to their media files automatically when inserted in to post.

Perhaps this is just me (and perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question), but I feel that this would work better if you were to use Javascript, especially since you want to target a specific class - .story. PHP would be used to retrieve original links of media files, if that can't be generated via JS.

You can create a block variation where the linkDestination and href attributes are preset. This enables you to add the core/image block from the block appender without having to set the attributes afterwards.
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { registerBlockVariation } from '@wordpress/blocks';

registerBlockVariation('core/image', {
  name: 'attachment-image',
  title: __('Attachment Image'),
  description: __('Image block preset with clickable link to image'),
  isActive: (blockAttributes) => {
    if (blockAttributes.linkDestination === 'media') {
      blockAttributes.href = blockAttributes.url;
    }

    return blockAttributes.linkDestination === 'media';
  },
  attributes: {
    linkDestination: 'media'
  },
  scope: ['inserter', 'transform', 'block']
});

Note: the example above abuses the validation to set the href attribute as you can't dynamically read the attributes from within the attribute, but this is necessary to get it to work.
